# Most efficient php if structure

Tags: php, performance

What runs faster?

Setting a default value and changing it-

```
    $foo = "";
    if($bar)
    {
        $foo = "someValue";
    }
```

Or-

```
    if($bar)
    {
        $foo = "someValue";
    }
    else
    {
        $foo = "";
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You absolutely should not be bothered with performance of a single `if` statement.

Also, consider:

```
$foo = $bar ? "" : "someValue"
```

Comment: I guess he have many if statements.. otherwise yes, there is no motivation to bother about just 1 statement

Comment: @DaNieL If he has a gazillion of `if` statements, that is clearly a code smell. Otherwise, this is not what he should be worried about.

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, the 2nd one "potentially".  First one you're potentially setting 2 values.  Second one you're definitely only setting one.

Its also a question though of code clarity.  If you've got 2 alternatives (e.g turn left or right) then use the "else" statement.  If you've got a 'normal' value vs a flag e.g http or https, then use the first one

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** becose you valorize a variable in base to another one, the isset() statement is *mandatory*.. so the 'faster one' is the second way becose, as David said, yoo valorize the $foo var just one time.

Also consider the Anton suggestion to use the short if syntax (dont know if it speed up the execution)

P.s: if your goal is to speed up many if like that one, use the ' instead of ", becose the content inside "" is being evalutated by php (in case it contain a variable:

Comment: isn't that true for both cases?

Comment: No, in the first case he assign the value of $foo before the if statement ;)

Comment: Without assign the variable 'default value' before the if statement, using the isset() function will slow (relatively) the execution

Comment: I have one word in reply to you, sir. DOH!

Comment: oh but wait.  he sets foo and then checks bar

Comment: no, not necessarily.  $urlString = "http"; if ($isSecure) {$urlString="https";} :-)